# JS Regex: how to remove first 2 zero's from "08/08/2017"

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, regex-group

I'm new to regex, and have been researching all night how to remove the first 2 zeros from a string like "08/08/2017" (without removing 0 in "2017")

The 5+ regex tutorials I've reviewed do not seem to cover what I need here.

The date could be any sysdate returned from the system. So the regex also needs to work for "12/12/2017"

Here is the best I have come up with:

```
let sysdate = "08/08/2017"
let todayminuszero = str.replace("0","");
let today = todayminus0.replace("0","");
```

It works, but obviously it's unprofessional.

From the tutorials, I'm pretty sure I can do something along the lines of this:
str.replace(/\d{2}//g,""),);
This pattern would avoid getting the 3rd zero in str.
Replacement String would have to indicate 8/8/
Not sure how to write this though.

Comment: Why not split it on day month and year and replace leading zero for any part you need. I think your code will break on "10/10/2017"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For date manipulation I would use other functions(best date related) but, this should do it, for the case that you stated. If you need other formats or so, I would suggest removing the zeros in an different way, but It all depends on you UseCase.

```js
let sysdate = "08/08/2017";
let todayminuszero = sysdate.replace(/0(?=\d\/)/gi,"");
console.info(todayminuszero);
```

> (?= ... ) is called Lookahead and with this you can see what is there, without replacing it
>   in this case we are checking for a number and a slash. `(?=\d\/)` 
>   here some more information, if you want to read about lookahead and more **http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html**

*A good place to test regex expressions is **https://regex101.com/** 
I always use this for more advance expressions, since it displays all matching groups and so, with a great explaination. Great resource/help, if you are learning or creating difficult Expressions.*

> **Info:** as mentioned by Rajesh, the `i` flag is not needed for this Expression, I just use it out of personal preference. This flag just sets the expression-match to *case insensitive*.

**--  Out of Scope, but may be interesting --**

A longer solution without regex could look like this:

```js
let sysdate = "08/08/2017";
let todayminuszero = sysdate.split("/").map(x => parseInt(x)).join("/");

console.info(todayminuszero);
```

Backside, this solution has many moving parts, the `split` function to make an array(´"08/08/2017"´ to ´["08", "08", "2017"]´), the `map` function, with a lambda function `=>` and the `parseInt` function, to make out of each string item a nice integer (like: `"08"` to `8`, ... ) and at last the `join` function that creates the final string out of the newly created integer array.

Comment: If you are processing dateString, what is the point of having `i` flag?

Comment: you don't need it, but for I personally always set those two flags, and remove them if the expression, explicitly doesn't need it. It's just my personal style.

Comment: @TomLord do you mean the `i` flag or the demo code? I am always open for improvement. Now that I am writing this is see some missing semicolons.

Comment: btw. I usually don't like chaining, but this seems to be the "trend". (but at least i didn't indent it) ;-)

Comment: I mean passing an `i` flag "by default", even when it's not needed. Case sensitivity is turned *off* by default, for good reason: It prevents unexpected matches, and (slightly) improves performance.

Comment: @TomLord Thanks for your response, I will revisit my style choice in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

you should use this

```js
let sysdate = "08/08/2017"
let todayminuszero = sysdate.replace(/(^|\/)0/g,"$1");
console.log(todayminuszero);
```

Comment: or `sysdate.replace(/\b0/g,"")`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function stripLeadingZerosDate(dateStr){
    return dateStr.split('/').reduce(function(date, datePart){
        return date += parseInt(datePart) + '/'
    }, '').slice(0, -1);
}

console.log(stripLeadingZerosDate('01/02/2016'));
console.log(stripLeadingZerosDate('2016/02/01'));
```

look at here

```
function stripLeadingZerosDate(dateStr){
return dateStr.split('/').reduce(function(date, datePart){
    return date += parseInt(datePart) + '/'
}, '').slice(0, -1);
```

}

```
console.log(stripLeadingZerosDate('01/02/2016'));// 1/2/2016
console.log(stripLeadingZerosDate('2016/02/01'));// "2016/2/1"
```

Comment: OP is using `/` as delimiter. I suggest using regex to split `/[\/-]/`

Answer (score -1):

By *first 2 zeros*, I understand you mean zero before `8` in month and in date.

You can try something like this:

#### Idea

- Create a regex that captures group of number representing date, month and year.
- Use this regex to replace values.
- Use a function to return processed value.

```js
var sysdate = "08/08/2017"
var numRegex = /(\d)+/g;

var result = sysdate.replace(numRegex, function(match){
  return parseInt(match)
});
console.log(result)
```

Comment: @downvoter, Feel free to highlight the mistake. This will help everyone.